# Jelly script to reset the issue resolution in JIRA

Tags: resolution, jira, jelly

I am trying to run a jelly script in JIRA to set the resolution to null for all my issues. The following script runs without errors and returns this:

```
<JiraJelly xmlns:jira='jelly:com.atlassian.jira.jelly.JiraTagLib' xmlns:log='jelly:log' xmlns:core='jelly:core' xmlns:jx='jelly:xml' xmlns:util='jelly:util'>org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue.NULL_VALUEorg.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue.NULL_VALUEorg.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue.NULL_VALUE.... </JiraJelly>
```

Here is the script.

```
<JiraJelly xmlns:jira="jelly:com.atlassian.jira.jelly.JiraTagLib" xmlns:util="jelly:util" xmlns:core="jelly:core" xmlns:jx="jelly:xml" xmlns:log="jelly:log">
        <jira:RunSearchRequest var="issues" />

        <core:forEach var="genericIssue" items="${issues}">
            <core:invokeStatic className="com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueImpl" method="getIssueObject" var="issue">
                <core:arg type="org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue" value="${genericIssue}"/>
            </core:invokeStatic>

            <core:invoke on="${issue}" method="setResolution">
                <core:arg type="org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue">org.ofbiz.core.entity.GenericValue.NULL_VALUE</core:arg>
            </core:invoke>

        </core:forEach>
</JiraJelly>
```

Does any one have any idea why this isn't working or have any ideas on how I might set the resolution to nothing?

Thank you!!

Comment: Tried running the RunSearchRequest with a filterid as well with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Updating issues via jelly in JIRA is a bit broken. The best example of how to make it work that I've seen is by using ActionDispatcher as shown on the docs page in a [comment](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Jelly+Examples?focusedCommentId=4227722#comment-4227722) by Alastair King.

Comment: mdoar's link no longer takes you to the comment. Here's an updated link: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Jelly+Examples?focusedCommentId=4227722#comment-4227722

Comment: Thanks Charlie Brown. All the Atlassian developer pages have moved to developer.atlassian.com, but the comments are gone.

Comment: Wow, that's super lame. I guess it won't be long for the same question to pop up on their "Answers" site.

Answer (score 0):

I know it can be done with Jelly runner, but i thinks that this would be easier to do so using the [Jira remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference) or the [Jira CLI](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/JIRA+Command+Line+Interface). A more elaborated example of the Jira remote API can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490566/jira-issue-reminder/11536935#11536935). If anyone wants me to post a working source code feel free to ask.