# Jira issue reminder

Tags: jira

How to create a notification via emails to a pre-defined mail group when an issue is open for 24/36/48 hrs.

There should be one reminder for any of those types (24/36/48) , and if an issue was re-opened the count should be restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally agree with Kuf's approach, but the **recent JIRA plugin releases [Automation Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.plugin.automation.jira-automation-plugin) and [PDF Automation Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.midori.jira.plugin.pdfautomation) enable to enhance it further**.

So, you define and update the scripted custom field, as written above. You create the saved filter with the JQL query, as written above.

(The interesting part starts here.)

You set up a new [automation rule](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/02/atlassian-support-uses-jira-automation-plugin/) with the Automation Plugin:

1. Define the CRON expression based trigger to match your preferred schedule (every 5 minutes, for example)
2. Select the "Send PDF" action to execute, choose a PDF template (if a simple issue list is enough, then use the "issue navigator" template) and enter the email addresses to ping.

The advantages of this over your original solution:

1. It is more maintainable: it is all plugin based, and all the fun happens internally in JIRA. No external dependencies, no scripts to maintain.
2. The PDF format allows nicer formatting and visualization possibilities (charts!) than a simple issue link.

*Disclaimer: I'm a developer of this paid JIRA add-on.*

Answer (score 2):

This is best achieved via [subscriptions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Receiving+Search+Results+via+Email).

First create a search filter for each type (24h, 36h, etc.). Note: at this point we have to be a bit more precise about what you mean by "24h open". I assume that you care about issues that are unassigned for to long.

So to filter out this issues you could use a filter like this:

```
created <= -24h and status = Open and assignee is null
```

If you want issues that have not been touched for 24h use "updated" instead of created in the above example. [Click here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching) on how to use the Jira query language.

Save the filter with a meaningful name (like e.g. "24h open").

Now under Issues->Manage Filters there is a column "subscriptions" where you can subscribe yourself or any Jira group for this filter. Just use the schedule daily and interval once per day, choose a convenient time and there you go.

Use the same technique for reopened issues but change the filter query to:

```
status = Reopened AND updated <= -24h
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a few issues with this method.

 - I want to receive the reminders once 24 hours have passed, if I will schedule it once a day, some issues might remain opened for up to 48 hours.

 - I want to receive only one reminder of each type (24h, 36h, 48h) only once for each issue.

 - using 'updated <= -24h' is not the right query since I want to select all issues that have an 'open'status' for over 24h/36h/48h.

Comment: If subscriptions don't work for you, then you probably want a custom service that runs every 24 hours and creates sets of issues to be sent in notifications. Maybe the Jelly script escalation approach will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

After lot's of searching I've solved it like this:

- Created a custom field called "Open since" - a 'Date Time' field to hold the time the issue has been opened.
- Created a custom field called "Notification" - a read only text field.
- Using the [Jira Scripting Suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490566/jira-issue-reminder#answer-11536935), I've created a post-function and placed it on every transition going to the 'Open' status. This is to keep the issue opening time.

the code:

```
from com.atlassian.jira import ComponentManager
from datetime import datetime

opend_since_field = "customfield_10001"

# get opened since custom field:
cfm = ComponentManager.getInstance().getCustomFieldManager()
# get current time
currentTime = datetime.today()
# save current time
issue.setCustomFieldValue(cfm.getCustomFieldObject(opend_since_field),currentTime)
```

- I've created a new filter to get the list of issues that are open for over 24h:

JQL:

```
project = XXX AND status= Open ORDER BY updated ASC, key DESC
```

- Lastly - I've used the [Jira remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference) - the [XML-RPC](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+XML-RPC+Overview) method to write a python script scheduled to run every 5 minutes. The script
  reads all the issued from the filter, pulls all of them that have an 'Open' status for over 24h/36h/48h, send a reminder email, and mark them as notified, so only one reminder of each type will be sent.

The python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Refer to the XML-RPC Javadoc to see what calls are available:
# http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/xmlrpc/XmlRpcService.html
# /home/issues_reminder.py

import xmlrpclib
import time
from time import mktime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import smtplib,email
from smtplib import SMTP 
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders

# Jira connction info
server = 'https://your.jira.com/rpc/xmlrpc'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
filter = '10302' # Filter ID
# Email definitions 
smtpserver = 'mail.server.com'
fromAddr = 'support@your.jira.com'
mail_user = 'jira_admin@your.domain.com'
mail_password = 'password'
toAddr = 'support@your.domain.com'
mysubject = "hrs Issue notification!!!"
opend_since_field = "customfield_10101"


COMMASPACE = ', '
def email_issue(issue,esc_time):
    # create html email
    subject = '['+issue+'] '+esc_time+mysubject
    html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" '
    html +='"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'
    html +='<body style="font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana">'
    html +='<p align="center"><img src="your_logo.jpg" alt="logo" height="43" width="198"></p> '
    html +='<p> The issue ['+issue+'] is open for over '+esc_time+' hours.</p>'
    html +='<p> A link to view the issue: https://your.jira.com/browse/'+issue+'.</p>'
    html +='<BR><p> This is an automated email sent from Jira.</p>'
    html +='</body></html>'
    emailMsg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    emailMsg['Subject'] = subject
    emailMsg['From'] = fromAddr
    emailMsg['To'] = toAddr
    emailMsg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
    # Send the email
    emailserver = SMTP(smtpserver) # ip or domain name of smtp server
    emailserver.login(mail_user, mail_password)
    emailserver.sendmail(fromAddr, [toAddr], emailMsg.as_string())
    emailserver.quit()
    return


s = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server)
auth = s.jira1.login(user, password)

esc12List = []
esc24List = []
esc48List = []


issues = s.jira1.getIssuesFromFilter(auth, filter)
print "Modifying issue..."
for issue in issues:
        creation = 0;
        # get open since time
        for customFields in issue['customFieldValues']:
                if customFields['customfieldId'] == opend_since_field :
                        print "found field!"+  customFields['values']
                        creation = customFields['values']
        if (creation == 0):
                creation = issue['created']
                print "field not found"
    creationTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time.strptime(creation, '%d/%b/%y %I:%M %p')))
    currentTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(time.gmtime()))
    delta = currentTime - creationTime
    esc12 = timedelta(hours=12)
    esc24 = timedelta(hours=24)
    esc48 = timedelta(hours=48)
    print "\nchecking issue "+issue['key']
    if (delta < esc12):
        print "less than 12 hours"
        print "not updating"
        continue
    if (delta < esc24):
        print "less than 24 hours"
        for customFields in issue['customFieldValues']:
            if customFields['customfieldId'] == 'customfield_10412':
                if customFields['values'] == '12h':
                    print "not updating"
                    break
                else:
                    print "updating !!!"
                    s.jira1.updateIssue(auth, issue['key'], {"customfield_10412": ["12h"]})
                    esc12List.append(issue['key'])
                    break
        continue
    if (delta < esc48):
        print "less than 48 hours"
        for customFields in issue['customFieldValues']:
            if customFields['customfieldId'] == 'customfield_10412':
                if customFields['values'] == '24h':
                    print "not updating"
                    break
                else:
                    print "updating !!!"
                    s.jira1.updateIssue(auth, issue['key'], {"customfield_10412": ["24h"]})
                    esc24List.append(issue['key'])
                    break
        continue
    print "more than 48 hours"
    for customFields in issue['customFieldValues']:
        if customFields['customfieldId'] == 'customfield_10412':
            if customFields['values'] == '48h':
                print "not updating"
                break
            else:
                print "updating !!!"
                s.jira1.updateIssue(auth, issue['key'], {"customfield_10412": ["48h"]})
                esc48List.append(issue['key'])
                break

for key in esc12List:
    email_issue(key,'12')
for key in esc24List:
    email_issue(key,'24')
for key in esc48List:
    email_issue(key,'48')
```

The main pros of this method is that it's highly customizable, and by saving the data to custom fields it's easy to create filters and reports to show issues that have been opened for a long time.