# Automatic state change of workflow on 20th date using groovy

Tags: groovy, workflow, jira

How to change the status of a jira workflow on every 20th day a month using groovy script?

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the status of workflow"? You want to change a status of an issue (transition), or change the name of the status in the workflow to affect all issues? Since jira is mostly event-based, I think that in any case you'll have to use an external timed script (cron or CI).

Comment: I want to change the status of an issue(transition).

Answer (score 0):

You can use open source command line client for Jira to achieve this such as the [python CLI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jira-cli) and [node.js CLI](https://github.com/tebriel/jira-cli). Another option would be to use [Jira remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Remote+API+Reference).

Using any of those tools, you can create a script that iterates over all of your issues and change their transitions. Than, add this script as a cron job to be executed on the 20th of each month.

you can check [Jira issue reminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490566/jira-issue-reminder/11536935#11536935) for an example of a script modifying issues from the remote API.